# convert vertical .txt file to dictionary without any library just python basic function

Tags: python, dictionary, txt

How to convert this .txt file
[txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmY49.png)

to this
[dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgfn4.png)

here is my code
input:

```py
file_harga_rumah = open("harga_rumah.txt", "r")
data_harga_rumah = file_harga_rumah.read()
file_harga_rumah.close()

key_harga_rumah = data_harga_rumah.replace("\n",",").split(",")
harga_rumah = []
for baris in key_harga_rumah:
    baris_harga_rumah = baris
    dict_harga_rumah = dict()
    for i in range(len(baris_harga_rumah)):
        harga_rumah[key_harga_rumah[i]] = dict_harga_rumah
    harga_rumah.append(harga_rumah[key_harga_rumah[i]])
```

output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-115-aeb7087f0ba0> in <module>
      9     dict_harga_rumah = dict()
     10     for i in range(len(baris_harga_rumah)):
---> 11         harga_rumah[key_harga_rumah[i]] = dict_harga_rumah
     12     harga_rumah.append(harga_rumah[key_harga_rumah[i]])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

i can't convert this txt file to dictionary please help:))))

Comment: Please update your question and upload your code but not photos

Answer (score 0):

example:

[image]

u can use dictReader:

```
input_file = csv.DictReader(open(r'c:\temp\file.txt'))
```

to display the result:

```
for row in input_file:
    print(row)
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a way for you to do this thing without using any import statement. It may confuse you a bit but works well

Here is how to do this

The Text file:

```
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
2,3,4
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

The function

```
def get_dict(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as fl:
        txt = fl.read()
    rows = txt.split('\n')
    columns = rows[0].split(',')
    data = []
    for value in rows[1:]:
        temp = {}
        for key in columns:
            temp[key] = value.split(',')[columns.index(key)]
    return data
```

Input

```
file_name = "file.txt"
data = get_dict(file_name)
```

Output

```
>>> data
[{'col1': '1', 'col2': '2', 'col3': '3'}, {'col1': '2', 'col2': '3', 'col3': '4'}, {'col1': '4', 'col2': '5', 'col3': '6'}, {'col1': '7', 'col2': '8', 'col3': '9'}]
```

Note: If you are using spaces with comma(,) use strip() eg. `text.strip()` to remove extra space in starting and ending of text.

Answer (score 0):

Input file:

```
tanah,bangunan,jarak_ke_pusat,harga
70,50,15,500
70,60,30,400
70,60,55,300
100,50,30,700
100,70,25,1000
100,70,50,650
120,100,20,2000
120,80,50,1200
150,100,50,1800
150,90,15,3000
```

Parse the file like this:

```
from pprint import pprint

with open('harga_rumah.txt', 'r') as f:
    rows = [row.rstrip() for row in f]

output_list = []
heading_list = rows[0].split(',')
for row in rows[1:]:
    row_dict = {}
    for heading in heading_list:
        row_dict[heading] = row.split(',')[heading_list.index(heading)]
    output_list.append(row_dict)

pprint(output_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'bangunan': '50', 'harga': '500', 'jarak_ke_pusat': '15', 'tanah': '70'},
 {'bangunan': '60', 'harga': '400', 'jarak_ke_pusat': '30', 'tanah': '70'},
 {'bangunan': '60', 'harga': '300', 'jarak_ke_pusat': '55', 'tanah': '70'},
 {'bangunan': '50', 'harga': '700', 'jarak_ke_pusat': '30', 'tanah': '100'},
 {'bangunan': '70', 'harga': '1000', 'jarak_ke_pusat': '25', 'tanah': '100'},
 {'bangunan': '70', 'harga': '650', 'jarak_ke_pusat': '50', 'tanah': '100'},
 {'bangunan': '100', 'harga': '2000', 'jarak_ke_pusat': '20', 'tanah': '120'},
 {'bangunan': '80', 'harga': '1200', 'jarak_ke_pusat': '50', 'tanah': '120'},
 {'bangunan': '100', 'harga': '1800', 'jarak_ke_pusat': '50', 'tanah': '150'},
 {'bangunan': '90', 'harga': '3000', 'jarak_ke_pusat': '15', 'tanah': '150'}]
```